# C++ method to return alphabet B when input is A so on till ZZ

Tags: c++, stdstring

C++ method to return alphabet `B` when an input is `A` so on till `Z` then if the input is `Z` the method should return `AA` if the input is `AA` the method should return `AB`, so on till `ZZ`. Please find a sample program which I was trying.

```
void getString(string s){

    for (char ch = 'A'; ch<= 'Z';)
    {
        cin >> ch;
        ch++;
        cout<< ch;
        if (ch = 'Z')
        {
            cout << "in loop";

            for (char k = 'A'; k<= 'Z';){

                for (char j = 'A'; j<= 'Z';j++){
                    char res = k + j;

                    cout << res;
                }
                k++;
                }               
        }       

    }
}

int main() {


getString("");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). There are many ways to debug, and just about all of them should have pointed out a very fatal flaw in your program: Using assignment instead of comparison for equality in a condition.

Comment: You also fall into a trap of making your program non-portable. There's no requirement in the C++ specification that `'A' <= 'Z'`. Neither is there a requirement that letters are consecutively encoded. Furthermore, even with [ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) encoding, `k + j` is wrong and will result in a value out of bound of 7-bit ASCII (most importantly it won't concatenate the two characters into a two-character string). You need to print the  two characters one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `if (ch == 'Z')` instead of `if (ch = 'Z')`

`=` operator is for assign a value to a variable. But `==` is a compare operator :

```
if (ch = 'Z')       // assign `Z` to ch and check if it's not `\0` (always true)
if (ch == 'Z')      // Compare ch with `Z`
```

With `char res = k + j;` you cannot concatenate characters, You should use of `strcat()` or use of `+` operator just for an element.

Try bellow :

```
void getString(string s)
{
    if(s.length() == 1)
    {
        if(s[0] == 'Z')
            cout << "AA";
        else
            cout << static_cast<char>(s[0] + 1);
    }
    else if(s.length() == 2)
    {
        if(strcmp(s.c_str(), "ZZ") == 0)
        {
            cout << "ZZ";
        }
        else
        {
            if(s[1] != 'Z')
            {
                cout << s[0] << static_cast<char>(s[1] + 1);
            }
            else if(s[1] == 'Z')
            {
                cout << static_cast<char>(s[0] + 1) << 'A';
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char res[3] = {0};
    cin >> res;
    getString(res);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @keskav: so better use `if ('Z'==ch)` so that if you miss the = it will give you an error.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd or just enable compiler warnings to get "warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses".

Comment: Thank you so much. I had placed = sign accidentally. Can anyone help me with the code? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @keshavsingh is your problem fixed?

Comment: throwing me error at this point  char res = strcat(k,j); error is 44 27 C:\Users\bharg\Documents\test1.cpp [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: @keshavsingh define `char res[3] = {0};` in first then  : `res[0] = k; res[1] = j;` instead of `strcat(k,j);`

Comment: Thanks so much @MohammadrezaPanahi it produced the result but with a twist . If The input is Y it is printing from AA to ZZ as in if conditon we are checking Y == 'Z'. Output shown below: A
B
C
D


Y
Zin loopAAABACADAEAF...............till ZZ

Comment: Thank you very much @MohammadrezaPanahi . Worked for me. :) Great help :)